# In Backbone should I still use a Collection if it's only ever going to be one Model?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm not sure what the accepted design pattern is for this. I can't seem to get anything to work properly without a collection present, and nobody else seems to be doing this.

Comment: The answer would be no -- send a model to the view if there's only one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can work with a view and a model just fine, there is no obligation to have a model in a collection, the collections are there to help you whenever you need work and make adjustments on a set of models.